# sympy Rational convert : 53/18 -t*109/18---> Rational(53,18)-t*Rational(109,18)

Tags: python, sympy

I want f1-->f2 convert

function convert pogram

or

I want f1 --> 391/540

why real number

```
from sympy import *
var('t')
myRat=Rational(11,30)
f1=         53/18 -t*         109/18
f2=Rational(53,18)-t*Rational(109,18)
f3=               -t*         109/18
f4=               -t*Rational(109,18)
print("# f1",f1.subs({t:myRat}))
print("# f2",f2.subs({t:myRat}))
print("# f3",f3.subs({t:myRat}))
print("# f4",f4.subs({t:myRat}))
# f1 0.724074074074074   ---> I want 391/540
# f2 391/540
# f3 -1199/540
# f4 -1199/540
```

tell me how to? convert to string

53/18 -t* 109/18  　 --> 　"53/18 - t * 109/18"

Comment: Python has two division operators: `/` which will return a float and `//` which will usually return an `int`.  In `f1`, since `/` takes higher presence than addition, you end up multiplying `t` by a floating point number. The approach in `f2` seems to work fine, otherwise you could use the builtin `fraction`.

Comment: That being said, you could use `sympy.simplify("53/18 - t * 109/18").subs({t: myRat})`.

Comment: Use `S(109)/18` or `Rational(109, 18)` to get a sympy `Rational` rather than a `float`